# GRAILS: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property.

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to debug a Grails application. Unfortunately, I have no prior experience in said language.

When I do **grails generate-all org.example.Book**, I get back a vague error:

```
Generating controller for domain class org.example.Book ...
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Event for class: SimpleTemplateScript6
    at SimpleTemplateScript6.run(SimpleTemplateScript6.groovy:22)
    at _GrailsGenerate_groovy.generateForDomainClass(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:88)
    at _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:48)
    at GenerateAll$_run_closure1.doCall(GenerateAll.groovy:42)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
Error running generate-all: No such property: Event for class: SimpleTemplateScript6
```

After looking at the generated org.example.BookController.groovy source, I noticed that it was not fully generated (stopped at List fields = []):

```
package org.example

// import needed for export plugin
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

class BookController {

    ...
    def exportService

    def export = {attrs ->
    def response = attrs.response
    List fields = []
```

This error *appears* to be caused by the following code in templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy:

```
<%=packageName ? "package ${packageName}\n\n" : ''%>

// import needed for export plugin
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

class ${className}Controller {

    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]^M

    def exportService

    ...

    def export = {attrs ->
    def response = attrs.response
    List fields = []
    <% excludedProps = Event.allEvents.toList() << 'version'
       allowedNames = domainClass.persistentProperties*.name << 'id' << 'dateCreated' << 'lastUpdated'
       props = domainClass.properties.findAll { allowedNames.contains(it.name) && !excludedProps.contains(it.name) && !Collection.isAssignableFrom(it.type) }
       Collections.sort(props, comparator.constructors[0].newInstance([domainClass] as Object[]))
       props.eachWithIndex {p, i -> %>fields.push("${p.name}"<%="\n"%><% } %>
       Map labels = [:]
       <% props.eachWithIndex { p, i -> %>labels.putAt("\${p.name}", "\${p.naturalName}")<%="\n "%><% } %>

       Map formatters = [:]
       Map parameters = [:]
       response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=${domainClass.propertyName}s.\${attrs.extension}")
       if("\${attrs.extension}" == "xml") {
            exportService.export(attrs.format, response.outputStream, attrs.exportList, fields, [:], formatters, parameters)
       } else {
            exportService.export(attrs.format, response.outputStream, attrs.exportList, fields, labels, formatters, parameters)
       }
    }
...
}
```

It appears that the def export {} block seems to be causing problems. Is there something wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the `Event` class? Is there an import for it?

Comment: You're right! I looked it up and it turned out that I needed to include the following line at the top of Controller.groovy:

   <% import grails.persistence.Event %>

Answer (score 0):

Check your domain class for syntax errors. Make sure that in your domain class, you've included necessary packages, in your case, package org.example.